# failed to run wicket examples on tomcat7

Tags: netbeans, wicket, tomcat7

I downloaded wicket examples 1.6.0 and built successfully in netbeans7.2. but got errors when I tried to deploy on tomcat 7:

Cannot deploy the module. The context.xml file seems to be broken. Check whether it is well-formed and valid.
The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.

> at
>   org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:210)
>      at
>   org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.ExecutionChecker.performDeploy(ExecutionChecker.java:178)
>      at
>   org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.ExecutionChecker.executionResult(ExecutionChecker.java:130)
>      at
>   org.netbeans.modules.maven.execute.MavenCommandLineExecutor.run(MavenCommandLineExecutor.java:212)
>      at
>   org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)

heres the contents in context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
<!-- <Loader className="org.atmosphere.util.AtmosphereClassloader"/> -->
<Loader delegate="true"/>
</Context>
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to run wicket in eclipse as it negates the requirement to mess around with an external tomcat instance.

If you are comfortable with eclipse and maven i would download wicket 1.6 example archetype via maven, import into eclipse and then in the test directory you can run the run.java class to get an internal jetty server host wicket for you.

this should get you started quickly without having to wrestle with tomcat configurations too.

Not really an answer but an alternative route to the same end point

Comment: as a btw; if you choose to do this i can support you in getting it up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Add parameter path to context tag, same path that app will be served:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/application-path-name/">
<!-- <Loader className="org.atmosphere.util.AtmosphereClassloader"/> -->
<Loader delegate="true"/>
</Context>
```

Answer obtained from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19454777/4178613) question.