# not able to deploy, context file broken

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

i used tomcat 7 and netbeans 7.4

when i start my web application i get

Cannot deploy the module. The context.xml file seems to be broken. Check whether it is well-formed and valid.
The module has not been deployed.

it's my context.xml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/shareDS" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          maxActive="50" maxIdle="10" maxWait="100000"
          username="${db.user}" password="${db.password}" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          url="${db.url}"
          timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="1800000" autoReconnect="true"
          removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="300" logAbandoned="true"/>
</Context>
```

when i try to validate my context file, i get

```
Cannot find the declaration of element 'Context'. [19]
```

any idea?

Comment: I'm stuck on the same issue, running Netbeans 8.0 and Tomcat 7.0.54. It seems that this is a Netbeans specific issue. The application I'm currently trying to run is perfectly running on IntelliJ, and on several servers with the context.xml used. But since I have to write a developers cookbook, I'm looking into the matter. Keep you posted.

Answer (score 10):

Figured it out. The Netbeans deployment process wants you to add 1 simple parameter to the Context tag, namely: path. It needs to know what path the application will be on.

For example, this was my (opening) Context tag:

```
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/sas/">
```

My application is deployed at the /sas/ context root.

And now, Netbeans deploys my application without any further errors.

FYI: the antiJARLocking is something I put in to avoid locking of JAR's. It's not mandatory. 
For more information on the antiJARLocking, refer to the documentation over at: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html