# Context.xml file is broken. what purpose of context.xml of java webapplication?

Tags: java, java-websocket

> ant -f D:\Documents\Documents\PRJ321\WebApp -Dnb.internal.action.name=run -Ddirectory.deployment.supported=true -DforceRedeploy=false -Dnb.wait.for.caches=true -Dbrowser.context=D:\Documents\Documents\PRJ321\WebApp run
>   init:
>   deps-module-jar:
>   deps-ear-jar:
>   deps-jar:
>   library-inclusion-in-archive:
>   library-inclusion-in-manifest:
>   compile:
>   compile-jsps:
>   In-place deployment at D:\Documents\Documents\PRJ321\WebApp\build\web
>   Cannot deploy the module. The context.xml file seems to be broken. Check whether it is well-formed and valid.
>   D:\Documents\Documents\PRJ321\WebApp\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1052: The module has not been deployed.
>   See the server log for details.
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
<Resource name="jdbc/mydatabase" 
          auth="Container" type="javax.sql.Datasource" 
          username="sa" password="22011998" 
          dirverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" url="jdbc:mysql://mysql.metawerx.net:3306/WebApp?autoReconnect=true"/>
</Context>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454777/not-able-to-deploy-context-file-broken This can be helpful.

Comment: Thank you... But it does not work for my case

Comment: I notice that you spelled 'dirverClassName' incorrectly . You didn't specify which version of Tomcat you are using, but you will find documentation for this here https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html